# LaTeX omitting certain terms in equation

Tags: equations, rendering

I'm trying to write an equation for a report but for some reason one term in brackets is not rendering.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}                      
\usepackage{gensymb}                    
\usepackage{amsmath}                    
\usepackage{amssymb}                    
\usepackage{wasysym}                    
\usepackage{physics}                    

\begin{document}{
\twocolumn
\section{Theoretical background}
\subsection{Domain wall oscillation}
    ...

    \begin{equation}
        \nu^{2} = (\frac{\gamma}{2\pi})^{2} \left[ \frac{\pi}{2} \pdv{H_x}{z} (\|H_x\|-8M) - \frac{1}{16}\pi^{2}\alpha^{2}(\|H_x\|-8M)^{2} \right]
    \end{equation}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here's my output

[image: Render of equation]

The first `(\|H_x\|-8M)` term is just being completely omitted for some reason, and I'm not sure why. It's a 2 column document, if that's relevant. I'm using TeXShop v 4.69 on MacOS.

The error log also doesn't seem to mention anything about it. This is line 110 of the document, and here's the log for the neighbouring lines.

```
l.77 \twocolumn
               [ [1]
Overfull \hbox (12.18076pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 99--99
[]\OT1/cmr/bx/n/12 Magnetic do-mains and do-main walls 

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/wasy/b/n' in size <7> not available
(Font)              Font shape `U/wasy/m/n' tried instead on input line 100.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `U/wasy/b/n' in size <5> not available
(Font)              Font shape `U/wasy/m/n' tried instead on input line 100.


Overfull \hbox (3.87979pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 105--106
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 mass per unit area $\OML/cmm/m/it/10 m[] \OT1/cmr/m/n/10 = (2\O
ML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^Y^^M[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ^^A)[] = (2\OML/cmm/m/it/10 ^^YE[]\OT1/c
mr/m/n/10 )[][]$
[2]
Overfull \hbox (1.25798pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 131--132
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 age do-main wall mo-tion at 10 MHz fre-quen-cies. Scan-

Overfull \hbox (7.46165pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 133--134
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Spin-polarised low-energy elec-tron mi-croscopy (SP-

Overfull \hbox (0.54503pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 133--134
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 com-plex and re-quires ex-pen-sive equip-ment, magneto-
[3]
Overfull \hbox (7.07283pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 143--144
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 of De Leeuw and Robert-son from 1975 [[]16[]] but adapted

Overfull \hbox (4.96864pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 148--149
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 The sam-ple it-self is mounted to a lin-ear $\OML/cmm/m/it/10 z
$\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 -translational
```

Thanks!

Comment: Look at `\pdv{H_x}{z]`. Is that brace/bracket pair intended?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: @mickep sorry, no that wasn't intended. My latex file has the right `\pdv{H_x}{z}` and it still gives the error

Comment: How or where is `\pdv` defined?

Comment: @Mico my apologies, just added an MWE. It's defined in the physics package

Comment: Kindly check for typo in this part - " \pdv{H_x}{z]" (These are not aligned, seems to be a typo there)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry, hope this is fine

Comment: Now you know why I discourage using `physics`. It seems full of bell and whistles, but it does so at the expense of a consistent syntax and *several* other issues.

Comment: @Dr.Sundar That was a typo in copying the text, I've edited it now. The source is fine and unfortunately the problem still persists

Comment: @egreg are there any alternatives you might recommend?

Comment: @AyushAgrawal `\newcommand{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}`, for instance. Anyway, see the duplicate question.